# Cannot find an eligible account when use google signup

Tags: kotlin

when i use New Google Sign-In API, i got an error
Cannot find an eligible account
As long as there is only one Google account logged into the phone, an error will be reported. If there are more than 2, there will be no problem and the login interface will be displayed.

I used the old login API without any problems, and the new version also had no problems before. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: Having the same issue, made a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301570453

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. We're looking into this. Further findings and follow ups will be added to the ticket that was opened.

Comment: Issue has been resolved.